# Is there a tool that can create a visual representation of my javascript code hierarchy

Tags: javascript, inheritance, plugins, visualization, hierarchy

I am looking for a tool that can create a visual representation of my JavaScript code-base. In particular I'd like to see:

- A extends B extends C
- A has member of type D
- A is used in XML file X
- Ideally this tool would be a plugin for Aptana or Eclipse.

*As a side note: Any plugins you can suggest that will make tracing dependencies easier is much appreciated: I'm familiar to Visual Studio's **"Go to Definition"** tool, and really want it for my JavaScript.*

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using dependency injection if A has  member of type D?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the best one so far and is some what recent:  http://www.objectplayground.com/

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want UML diagrams for your Javascript code.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802162/javascript-uml-diagrammer
http://objectmix.com/javascript/705504-class-diagrams-javascript.html
http://jsuml.gaertner-network.de/

As for the side, note, dependency management, [JavaScript dependency management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3202606/javascript-dependency-management)

Possibly interesting framework for you, http://knockoutjs.com/

Sorry to just point you to other posts but they seem to address your
questions.