# Is it possible to programmatically determine if a javascript file can be deferred?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on optimizing my site, and one of the things Google PageSpeed is suggesting is to "defer parsing of JavaScript".   I tried deferring all of my javascript files,  but that breaks some functionality.  I need some to load before and some after.   Is there a way to determine this programmatically?

Comment: I am not sure what you are looking for. Something like require.js?

Comment: You want to parse the file's contents? Anything is possible with enough time. I doubt it would be cost effective though.

Comment: Anyway, have you heard about HTML5's `async` and `defer` attributes?

Comment: I don't think you can programmatically determine whether a functionality needs to be loaded in `head` or can be fetched asynchronously. Don't you know that yourself?

Comment: What you are looking for is Javascript dependency management. I would say its not possible. More details are discussed here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3202606/javascript-dependency-management